# Are questions about personal theories on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have an new question about [Paul's relation to Jonathan](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32176/20).  The OP admits its his own historical theory, uncorroborated by anyone. Thus he's seeking that corroboration here.

> It is my own speculation, but someone else may very well have thought of it earlier.

Is this permitted here?

It seems to me in the past we have ruled *against* such questions, although generally they are questions more along the lines of morality. "I reason that it might be permitted to sleep with my girlfriend because... does any church agree with me?"

Admittedly, this Paul question is demonstrably *more constructive* than our typical user-created theology questions... But does that change the fundamental nature?

Comment: @DavidStratton: Thanks, Your search skills are better than mine. :)

Comment: I like this particular question because it is more History than theology, and history has been on-topic so long as it is related to Christianity or Christian figures.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this to Meta.

As the poster of the disputed question, I am biased, but as [fredsbend's comment](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3955/3331#comment-9455) indicates this is a *history* question and **not** a theology question. In my opinion, it should be no more off-topic (in terms of being new theology) than ["What is the evidence that suggests that the Apostle Paul was married?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/11455/3331).

The theological content (that the speculation has some devotional appeal) is motivation for the significance of the question to the asker **not** a request for indications that the devotional/theological aspect is valid, accepted by others, or rejected by others.

(Even the bonus question, which is much less justifiable, is of the nature of "What is the earliest known writing proposing X?" That was *motivated* in some part for a desire to know if others considered the possibility and thought it interesting enough to record, which is *vaguely* similar to asking if anyone agreed with it.)

I can understand if it is viewed as "too localized". Asking if there is any evidence that Paul was a descendant of Jonathan is **much** less broadly interesting than what evidence there is that he was married, but it is a concrete question with a answer based on historical information.

Comment: I think there's a strong difference between the marital status of Paul (on which many Christian historians have commented) and a personally proposed theory.

Comment: @Flimzy That is why I said closing as "too localized" would be understandable. (That the question got 2 upvotes might *hint* that there is at least **some** general interest.) As a history question it avoids some of the issues with theology questions. Perhaps a more comparable question would be "Was the bishop of X present at the council of Nicea?" (though that would be better generalized as "Is there a list of all bishops present at the council of Nicea?"; my question does not admit such generalization). The obscurity of the question is why I asked it.

Comment: It would also require specifying *which* council of Nicea... :)

Comment: @Flimzy If this question should be closed, than [one of my other questions](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/12100/3331) should be closed as well. It is obscure **and** based on *theology*. When I asked if that question was close-worthy (for a different reason), [Caleb's answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1484/3331) did not indicate that it was problematic, though perhaps he was only considering it in terms of the one issue and not general close-worthiness.

Comment: That question seems distinct to me, since it's specifically about Augustine's theology.

Comment: @Flimzy Doesn't that make it *more* localized?

Comment: No,that makes it on-topic because it's about a defined theological position (beliefs held/written about by Augustine).  If you can find a theologian (or historian) who wrote about Paul's relation to Jonathan, then a question about that would be clearly on topic as well.

Comment: @Flimzy But it is about a **personally invented** *extension* of that position **and** specifically asking if anyone else had suggested such. So if I can find the answer to my question, I can ask it? Sigh.

Comment: That's what this meta question is asking. :)  If we are allowed to invent theology and/or historical theories here, what's to stop someone from creating ridiculous claims?  "Is Abraham Lincoln related to David?" "Is it moral for Martians to have pre-marital sex?" Etc... I think we can agree that those two questions *are* ridiculous in a way yours is not. The question I'm asking is, where is that line drawn?